# How to make width of a view dependent on other view in a recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-view

I want to measure the width of a cardview and match to the cardview that is on its outside, to get a clear understanding I will attach an image along with the question:

[image]

Here, the inner cardview should be same width of the outer cardview in every case where inner cardview is the reply chat bubble and outer is the chat message bubble.

I have tried extending the cardview:

```
public class ExtendCardView extends CardView {

Integer newWidth;

public ExtendCardView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ExtendCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}


@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    newWidth= MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
      super.onMeasure(newWidth, heightMeasureSpec);

}

public Integer getNewWidth() {
    return newWidth;
}

public void setNewWidth(Integer newWidth) {
    this.newWidth = newWidth;
}}
```

and on the onBindView of adapter I have added a view tree observer to change the width:

```
((CardView) holder).inner_card_view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            //((CardView) holder).inner_card_view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

            ((CardView) holder).inner_card_view.setNewWidth(((CardView) holder).outer_card_view.getNewWidth());
            //now we can retrieve the width and height
            //...
            //do whatever you want with them
            //...
            //this is an important step not to keep receiving callbacks:
            //we should remove this listener
            //I use the function to remove it based on the api level!

            if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                ((CardView) holder).inner_card_view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            else
                ((CardView) holder).inner_card_view.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
```

What is the perfect way to achieve something like this, here is my layout file for the cardview:

```
      <com.example.ui.view.ExtendCardView
    android:id="@+id/outer_card"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">


        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <com.example.ui.view.ExtendCardView
                android:id="@+id/inner_card"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:minWidth="80dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/red"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="0dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/rel_layout"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="15dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_user_name"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/lin_layout"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@id/tv_user_name"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/iv_type"
                                android:layout_width="18dp"
                                android:layout_height="18dp"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                                android:tint="@color/dark_grey"
                                android:visibility="gone" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_message"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:autoLink="web"
                                android:maxLines="3" />
                        </LinearLayout>


                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_media"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:visibility="gone" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </com.nodd.nodd.ui.view.ExtendCardView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_reply_message"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/inner_card"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:autoLink="web"
                android:linksClickable="true"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textColorLink="@color/linkedin_blue" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tv_reply_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/inner_card"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</com.example.ui.view.ExtendCardView>
```

Comment: match_parent for inner cardview?

Comment: that extends the card to match the screen size

Comment: As much I can understand you want nested CardView which is adjusted according to reply post size. And Reply post is also in CardView. Try `android:setWidth="wrap_content"` for both of the cards. And for the inner CardView just add `android:layout_margin="5dp"`.

Comment: in a case where the inner cardview has less width and wraps the content, what would you propose for that?

Comment: and what is setwidth?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html).

> **ConstraintLayout** allows you to create large and complex layouts with a flat view hierarchy (no nested view groups). It's similar to RelativeLayout in that all views are laid out according to relationships between sibling views and the parent layout, but it's more flexible than RelativeLayout and easier to use with Android Studio's Layout Editor.

You can put your inner card in a **ConstraintLayout** and adjust its size by the outer card, without measuring and setting sizes.

Since `match_parent` is not allowed in **ConstraintLayout**, set `layout_height` and/or `layout_width` to `0dp` (adjust `layout_margin` properties to add space between the inner and outer cards).

In your case you'd get something like:

```
<com.example.ui.view.ExtendCardView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

    android:id="@+id/inner_card"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:minWidth="80dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/red"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp">

    <!-- ExtendCardView content -->

</com.nodd.nodd.ui.view.ExtendCardView>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

CardView has default paddings, so create a CustomCardView class that extended from CardView and customize it by removing paddings OR use other layouts for your card root (RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, ...)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is perfect but it should solve your problem.  There are two places that prevent your inner card from being the same width as the outer card.  The 1dp margin you set in the inner card & the 2dp padding you set in the `RelativeLayout` that is the inner cards parent.  By setting both of these to 0, you should be able to get the inner card the same width as the outer.  You need to give the `RelativeLayout` an id.  I used `card_layout`.  Then place this logic where you know whether there should be margins or not.

```
    int margin;
    int padding;

    if(needsMargins) {
        margin = 1;
        padding = 2;
    } else {
        margin = 0;
        padding = 0;
    }

    CardView cardView = (CardView)findViewById(R.id.inner_card);
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params =
            (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)cardView.getLayoutParams();
    params.setMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin);
    cardView.requestLayout();

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.card_layout);
    relativeLayout.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
```